# mysql installation error on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, mysql

After I installed MySQL-server I got the error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
MySQL-cluster-community-client-core : Depends: mysql-cluster-community-client-plugins (= 8.0.32-1ubuntu22.04) but it is not going to be installed
    E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried to delete the package and reinstall it again, I tried to install the unmet dependency. Also rebooting the system doesn't work. I also checked is there any ongoing process but there isn't.

I tried all of these commands, but I am getting the error.

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install 
sudo apt reinstall
sudo dpkg --configure --force-overwrite -a
sudo apt-get clean
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt purge mysql-server
sudo apt purge libmysqlclient21 
sudo dpkg-i ~/Downloads/mysql-apt-config_0.8.16-1_all.deb 
sudo dpkg -i mysql-{common,community-client,client,community-server,server)_*.deb
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Comment: What errors or info did you get when you did the apt --fix-broken install ?

Comment: As Ubuntus mysql-server package has no dependency to "mysql-cluster-community-client-plugins", I assume you are not using the package from Ubuntu repository.

Comment: Here is the error `E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
`

Comment: Here is the error after I type sudo: `dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-community-server-co
re_8.0.32-1ubuntu22.04_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/ibd2sdi', which is also in package mysql-cluster-
community-server-core 8.0.32-1ubuntu22.04
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-community-server-core_8.0.32-1ubuntu22.04_amd64.d
eb
`